# Windows explorer-like navigation buttons

Tags: c#, winforms

Is there a way to add "navigation buttons" in c# windows forms application? How can I get this control?

[image: navigation buttons]

Comment: Am pretty sure you'll have to roll your own or check for someone who already did that..

Comment: Depends on your application. What does it do? How do you expect back/forward to behave in your app?

Comment: I would like just to have buttons and assign my action to it.

Comment: Not every UI gadget is a control.  This is just a bitmap, displayed inside a [Rebar control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774373%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), Microsoft's favorite toolbar gadget.  You'll get pretty close with a button inside a ToolStrip that uses an icon.  DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea() is used as well.

Answer (score 2):

Just download images you like from the internet (search for "free arrows icons"), set them as a source of the `PictureBox` component and set them `Click()` action.

```
private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Test");
}
```

You can load an image to a picturebox by clicking a small arrow on the component as shown on the image.

[image]

Comment: Here's some search results for icons (WARNING: be vary of copyright restrictions!) - http://www.bing.com/images/search?q=windows+back+button+icons&qpvt=windows+back+button+icons&FORM=IGRE#a